# Sorting the rows based on a particular column value using groovy

Tags: groovy

I am totally new to groovy script/java script and I need some help to sort the below rows based on the 3rd column value [eg 12345685]:. Also while sorting ,the A record should come first followed by B and C.

**Expected Input:**

```
C;3456;12345685;xxxx;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;651326365;xxxx;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
A;3456;12345685;298, Val Ste-Croix;;;;;;LUX;2055;Luxembourg;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;651326365;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;456;;;;;;;LUX;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;54321;;;;;;;BEL;4321;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;114;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;12345685;xxxx;;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;M;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
B;3456;651326365;xxxx;;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;F;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
```

**Expected output:**

```
A;3456;12345685;298, Val Ste-Croix;;;;;;LUX;2055;Luxembourg;Dutch;;;;;
B;3456;12345685;xxxx;;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;M;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;12345685;xxxx;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
A;3456;651326365;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;651326365;xxxx;;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;F;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;651326365;xxxx;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
A;3456;456;;;;;;;LUX;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;54321;;;;;;;BEL;4321;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;114;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
```

I need some help to sort the below rows based on the 3rd column value [eg 12345685]:. Also while sorting ,the A record should come first followed by B and C.

Comment: what sort order for 3rd col exactly should it be? in what regard the `12345685` is smaller than `456`?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for responding..There is no such order required neither ascending or descending required in column , but we need to group the similar items, where as in the column 1 values should come in order A, B, C like below       
A;3456;12345685;298, Val Ste-Croix;;;;;;LUX;2055;Luxembourg;Dutch;;;;;
B;3456;12345685;xxxx;;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;M;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;12345685;xxxx;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be one way to do it:

```
String input = """C;3456;12345685;xxxx;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;651326365;xxxx;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
A;3456;12345685;298, Val Ste-Croix;;;;;;LUX;2055;Luxembourg;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;651326365;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;456;;;;;;;LUX;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;54321;;;;;;;BEL;4321;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;114;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;12345685;xxxx;;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;M;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
B;3456;651326365;xxxx;;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;F;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;"""

String output = input.split("\n")
        .collect { it.split(";", 4) }
        .sort { it[2] + ";" + it[0] }
        .collect { it.join(";") }
        .join("\n")

assert output == """A;3456;114;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;12345685;298, Val Ste-Croix;;;;;;LUX;2055;Luxembourg;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;12345685;xxxx;;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;M;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;12345685;xxxx;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
A;3456;456;;;;;;;LUX;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;54321;;;;;;;BEL;4321;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;651326365;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;651326365;xxxx;;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;F;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;651326365;xxxx;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;"""
```

Answer (score 2):

If only sorting inside a group is desired, a single-operation one-liner with re-ordering of CSV-parts in `replaceFirst` would do:

```
String txt = '''\
C;3456;12345685;xxxx;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;651326365;xxxx;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
A;3456;12345685;298, Val Ste-Croix;;;;;;LUX;2055;Luxembourg;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;651326365;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;456;;;;;;;LUX;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;54321;;;;;;;BEL;4321;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;114;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;12345685;xxxx;;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;M;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
B;3456;651326365;xxxx;;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;F;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;'''

String res = txt.readLines().sort{ it.replaceFirst( /(\w+);\d+;(\d+);.*/, '$2 $1' ) }.join( '\n' )

assert res == '''\
A;3456;114;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;12345685;298, Val Ste-Croix;;;;;;LUX;2055;Luxembourg;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;12345685;xxxx;;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;M;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;12345685;xxxx;2021-09-17T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;
A;3456;456;;;;;;;LUX;;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;54321;;;;;;;BEL;4321;;Dutch;;;;;;
A;3456;651326365;;;;;;;;;;Dutch;;;;;;
B;3456;651326365;xxxx;;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;F;;;;tobefilled;;;;tobefilled;;;;;
C;3456;651326365;xxxx;2011-04-04T00:00:00.000;tobefilled;;;;;'''
```